# ssl communication with postgresql in Ruby DBI Module

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ssl

I want to connect the postgresql db server over ssl enabled mode. In Ruby, am using dbi module to connect the database. But, dbi is not seem to be supporting ssl communication.

Is there any alternative to achieve this ? ( I would to prefer to use only dbi module).

Somewhere I read pg module supports ssl communication. But, I have more dependency  if I use pg.

Comment: _dbi is not seem to be supporting ssl communication_: can you elaborate on that? Such a module is not supposed to care whether the traffic is encrypted or not, this is driven by configuration on the server and connect string or env variables on the client.

Comment: I read the dbi documentation, I don't find any such configuration to enable `sslmode=require` (or) to pass in the connection string. Server is configured properly with sslmode. It works fine with perl,php clients. If you have updated document on dbi for enabling ssl,pls share.

Comment: Either `sslmode` is accepted among the driver-specific options (which are not going to be documented in dbi since dbi is driver-independant), or you may set the `PGSSLMODE` environment variable. Also `prefer` being the default sslmode, in the absence of any client-side setting, ssl is going to be used if it's available without dbi or dbd::pg even knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using DBI? If you can try with [pg](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg) gem, because it will support SSL and since it's the default used in rails application will give you an extra confidence if you find any issues.

Also to use SSL make sure your ruby is compiled with SSL support:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
```